# Searching a Sorted Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, java.util.scanner, binary-search-tree

I am trying to search through a Binary Tree for a user entered value and I am having issues with the searching. I want to return the branches of the tree leading up to the search term, or the path to where the search term would be added. The path would be the node value, plus an arrow pointing left OR right indicating the branch taken.
i.e. search:6; 20 <- 10 <-  5 -> 6 OR 20 <- 10 <- 5 -> Entry Would Go Here

My Issue, I believe, lies in the search methods. The code compiles, but when a search is run, I get the default value returned- null.

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver {
    /*****
     * Main
     *
     * @param args Command Line Arguments
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException {
        //Locale Objects and Variables
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loop;

        //Continuation Loop
        do {
            //Fill the Tree
            System.out.println("Adding Initial Ints");
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                System.out.print("\nEnter an Int: ");
                root.add(scan.nextInt());
            }

            //Search Prompt
            System.out.print("\nSearch For: ");
            System.out.print(root.search(scan.nextInt()));

            //Continuation Statement
            System.out.println("Continue? Yes to cont: ");
            String input = scan.next();

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("YES") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                loop = true;
            } else {
                loop = false;
            }   //IF-ELSE Tree
        } while (loop); //DO-WHILE LOOP
    }   //MAIN
}   //DRIVER
```

Tree Node Class:

```
public class TreeNode {

    //Instance Variables
    private int data;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;


    /*****
     * Constructor
     * Constructs a new TreeNode Object with the 3 instance variables passed
     *
     * @param initialData   int value held by the object
     * @param initialLeft   left link
     * @param initialRight  right link
     */
    public TreeNode(int initialData, TreeNode initialLeft, TreeNode initialRight) {
        data = initialData;
        left = initialLeft;
        right = initialRight;
    }   //TreeNode

    /*****
     * Constructor
     * Constructs the Object with only the data passed
     *
     * @param initialData   Data to give the node
     */
    public TreeNode(int initialData) {
        data = initialData;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }   //TreeNode

    /*****
     * Constructor
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public TreeNode() {

    }   //TreeNode


    /*****
     * Add
     * Add a new item to the tree, sorting as it adds. Left if the new info is less than the current node, Right if greater than
     *
     * @param info  Data for the new Node
     */
    public void add(int info) {

        /*Determines where to add the new information*/
        if (this == null) {
            setData(info);
        } else if (this.isLeaf()) {
            if (info < data) {
                left = new TreeNode(info);
            } else {
                right = new TreeNode(info);
            }
        } else if (info < data) {
            left.add(data);
        } else if (info > data) {
            right.add(data);
        } else if (info == data) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Input--Duplicate");
        }else {
            System.out.print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG---TREENODE_dot_ADD");
        }   //IF-ELSE Tree
    }   //ADD


    /*****
     * Search
     * Searches for the entry in the tree
     *
     * @param entry int to search for in the tree
     * @return the location of the int in the tree
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    public String search(int entry) throws NullPointerException {
        String result = new String();

        if (data == entry) {
            return result + data;
        } else if (this.isLeaf()) {
            return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";

        }else if (entry < data) {
            if (left.isLeaf())
                return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";
            left.search(entry, result + data + " <- ");

        } else if (entry > data) {
            if (right.isLeaf())
                return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";
            right.search(entry, result + data + " <- ");
        }   //IF-ELSE Tree
        return null;
    }   //SEARCH

    /*****
     * Search
     * Searches for the Entry in the Tree. Also receives a String to append with the new result information
     *
     * @param entry
     * @param result
     * @return The location of the entry in the tree
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    public String search(int entry, String result) throws NullPointerException {
        if (data == entry) {
            return result + data;
        } else if (this.isLeaf()) {
            return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";

        }else if (entry < data) {
            if (left.isLeaf())
                return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";
            left.search(entry, result + data + " <- ");

        } else if (entry > data) {
            if (right.isLeaf())
                return result + " Not Found, Would Go Here";
            right.search(entry, result + data + " <- ");
        }   //IF-ELSE Tree
        return null;
    }   //Search


    /*****
     * Is Leaf
     * Determines if the node has any children
     *
     * @return true if this node is a leaf
     */
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (right == null && left == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   //IF-ELSE TREE
    }   //IS LEAF


    /*****
     * Remove Leftmost
     * Deletes the node that follows the tree to the left
     *
     * @return Used to recursively access the Tree
     */
    public TreeNode removeLeftmost() {
        if (left == null)
            return right;
        else {
            left = left.removeLeftmost( );
            return this;
        }   //IF-ELSE TREE
    }   //REMOVE LEFTMOST


    /*****
     * Remove Rightmost
     * Deletes the node that follows the tree to the right
     *
     * @return Used to recursively access the Tree
     */
    public TreeNode removeRightmost() {
        if (right == null)
            return left;
        else {
            right = right.removeRightmost( );
            return this;
        }   //IF-ELSE TREE
    }   //REMOVE RIGHTMOST


    /*****
     * Size
     * Determines the size of the tree
     *
     * @return The number of nodes in the tree
     */
    public int size() {
        if (this == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + left.size() + right.size();
        }   //IF-ELSE Tree
    }   //SIZE


    /*****
     * Tree Copy
     * Makes a copy of the Tree
     *
     * @param source root to start the copy
     * @return a Tree rooted at source
     * @throws OutOfMemoryError
     */
    public static TreeNode treeCopy(TreeNode source) throws OutOfMemoryError {
        TreeNode leftCopy, rightCopy;

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            leftCopy = treeCopy(source.left);
            rightCopy = treeCopy(source.right);
            return new TreeNode(source.data, leftCopy, rightCopy);
        }   //IF-ELSE Tree
    }   //TREE COPY


    /*****
     * Get Right
     * Retrieve the child on the right
     *
     * @return the right child node
     */
    public TreeNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }   //GET RIGHT

    /*****
     * Get Left
     * Retrieve the child on the left
     *
     * @return The left child node
     */
    public TreeNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }   //GET LEFT

    /*****
     * Get Data
     * Retrieve the data of the current node
     *
     * @return the data of the current node
     */
    public Integer getData() {
        return data;
    }   //GET DATA


    /*****
     * Get Leftmost Data
     * Follows the tree to the left, and gets the data
     *
     * @return the data all the way on the left
     */
    public Integer getLeftmostData() {
        if (left.isLeaf()) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return left.getLeftmostData();
        }   //IF-ELSE TREE
    }   //GET LEFTMOST DATA

    /*****
     * Get Rightmost Data
     * Follows the tree to the right, and gets the data
     *
     * @return the data all the way on the right
     */
    public Integer getRightmostData() {
        if (right.isLeaf()) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return right.getRightmostData();
        }   //IF-ELSE TREE
    }   //GET RIGHTMOST DATA


    /*****
     * Set Data
     * sets the current data to data
     *
     * @param data new data for node
     */
    public void setData(Integer data) {
        this.data = data;
    }   //SET DATA

    /*****
     * Set Left
     * points current left to left
     *
     * @param left node to point left branch at
     */
    public void setLeft(TreeNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }   //SET LEFT

    /*****
     * Set Right
     * Points current right to right
     *
     * @param right node to point right branch at
     */
    public void setRight(TreeNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }   //SET RIGHT
}   //TREE NODE
```